# What is difference between dialog with jcr:primaryType as cq:TabPanel and jcr:primaryType as cq:Dialog

Tags: aem

As per the [documentation](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/developing/components.html) the dialog as cq:Dialog, which will provide a single tab - as in the text component, or if you need multiple tabs, as with the textimage component, the dialog can be defined as cq:TabPanel. When I open the dialog of text and textimage components both has multiple tabs in it.

So what is the difference between cq:Dialog and cq:TabPanel?

Text Image component Dialog
[image: Text Image component Dialog]

Text component dialog

[image: Text component dialog]

Answer (score 0):

`cq:dialog` and `cq:tabPanel` are nodeTypes assigned to `jcr:primaryType`.

As per jcr [documentation](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/jcr/node-types.html) -

> The primary node type of a node usually defines node structure (i.e.,
>   allowed and required child nodes and properties) related to the
>   problem domain being modeled.

You can see the details for each nodeType defination in CRX explorer - Node Type Administration - `/crx/explorer/nodetypes/index.jsp`

The rendering of the node hierarchy is handled by xtype defined for these nodes which can be dialog (/libs/cq/ui/widgets/source/widgets/Dialog.js) or tabPanel (/libs/cq/ui/widgets/source/ext/source/widgets/TabPanel.js)

Each of these scripts are responsible for rendering the node hierarchy to show you the dialog/window/tabpanel

You can read the documentation defined in each of the scripts. Dialog can very well contain tabpanels refer to page's dialog box whose xtype is dialog but the node hierarchy defines tabpanel as well.